# Grouped samples for svm classification

Tags: svm, libsvm, svmlight

I'm trying to classify some samples in to two different classes. each sample contains several features. But the problem is these samples belong to specific groups and each feature represent some property of that specific group. 
generally my data looks like this:

```
+1 1:547.6949 3:-122.99 4:-150.7976 5:-39.5595 6:-39.31721
-1 1:165.0353 3:-108.6274 4:-155.5586 5:-25.6145 6:-24.43071
-1 1:232.7848 3:-134.1802 4:-157.5643 5:-39.3388 6:-39.202710
-1 1:299.3863 3:-125.8626 4:-150.9111 5:-49.781 6:-52.444
-1 1:161.2316 3:-120.7769 4:-167.4669 5:-26.4132 6:-26.4737
-1 1:334.6234 3:-129.6332 4:-148.9993 5:-58.6543 6:-61.318
-1 1:203.4685 3:-121.9352 4:-158.4352 5:-39.1206 6:-39.086
-1 1:206.0046 3:-126.0539 4:-158.7209 5:-41.1821 6:-43.845
-1 1:229.0727 3:-107.8596 4:-160.4539 5:-40.8166 6:-43.4803
-1 1:202.8949 3:-137.3044 4:-166.1187 5:-36.4276 6:-37.438
-1 1:361.9454 3:-88.4864 4:-160.604 5:-27.7027 6:-23.787
+1 1:491.9685 3:-98.0369 4:-155.9668 5:-37.3844 6:-33.716 
-1 1:778.6312 3:-115.5249 4:-148.5153 5:-54.9574 6:-59.09651
-1 1:413.1565 3:-92.4645 4:-159.4521 5:-35.5019 6:-29.4924
-1 1:501.4577 3:-105.343 4:-156.6044 5:-39.2832 6:-43.42
-1 1:487.5412 3:-115.4553 4:-155.5021 5:-47.0739 6:-44.568
-1 1:445.5218 3:-109.6812 4:-157.8129 5:-51.4686 6:-45.212
-1 1:316.3106 3:-93.2688 4:-162.7669 5:-31.5366 6:-28.482
-1 1:284.8187 3:-95.0161 4:-154.7459 5:-37.6311 6:-25.738
-1 1:391.9559 3:-108.8012 4:-157.7027 5:-40.0802 6:-44.219
```

these are samples of two groups of data in each there is only one (+1) class and the rest is (-1). each group has equal size of 10 samples. My question is, how can I use a SVM classifier which considers this grouping. Or if SVM is not the best choice, what do you suggest?

Comment: What is your concern about these groups? just the unbalanced number of samples per class? or is there any other hidden feature that makes groups special?

Comment: Actually the number of samples per each class are equal. My only concern is if it is necessary for classier to be aware of these groups or it should classify the whole samples together. The range of features for each group could be different but the pattern is more and less same.